# Manage files with PhoneGap - Templating engine?

Tags: html, templates, architecture, cordova

I'm developing a mobile application in HTML/CSS/JavaScript using PhoneGap.

The question I have is how to manage files in my project. It seems that the application runs faster if all the HTML is placed into one file. In my case, my application should contain several pages and I can't think dealing with a more-than-2000-lines index.html, repeating each time same code for different views.

I'm coming to you to know what solutions you've found to make something simple that a foreign developer could understand and work on easily.

I'm using jQuery Mobile Beta 1. I've heard about jQuery tmpl which appears to me as a good solution to clear the code and reuse HTML, but is there another trick?

Thank you for your answers. Hope this topic would be useful for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap are not support multipage app. But mustache for js https://github.com/janl/mustache.js could help with managing of multiple html files.